# Home Page Layout not showing up properly for users (Lightning)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-home-page

I have created a home page and assigned it to a profile for admin the page is coming as I set it up, but for users it isn't. I have used report chart component. I have attached a screenshot. Any help will be appreciated [image]

Answer (score 1):

Admin can see it, but user cannot? Hmm, sounds like a permissions issue. Does the user have access to the reports folder?

If you are not rendering a report as a single user ("viewing data as") then the report data is also restricted to what the user can see.

Check out this link for more. [Reporting Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_reports_control_access.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Comment: I can see the reports when I am logged in with the user credentials..